# implement smoothing methods in fragment shader in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, fragment-shader, cg

i'm trying to make a smoothed model from a 3d texture in unity3d game engine.
but problem is here, the model is not smoothed and the slices are obviously visible , i also had some changes on my shader , but i didn't see a big different .

finally i found two good method for smoothing :
[image]
[image]

but i dont know how to implement this methods, anybody knows how i can implement this methods on my shader in unity using hlsl/cg language ?

Comment: maybe you should ask the author of these papers

Comment: where i can find papers author ?!?! i just have that papers and no anymore ...

Comment: idk you found those methods didn't you? The article should have an author and thus a contact. it's as much as anyone could possibly help unless you give us some code.

Comment: well, on the first slide you have provided there is a reference to `Heidrich and Keller`s publication from 2001 on interleaved sampling.. for the other method there should be a reference in that presentation as well (otherwise it is the presenters own work) (this looks like a presentation to at least)